# Implementing `waitBoth` function in the `async` library

Tags: haskell, asynchronous

I am currently going through the implementation of the [async](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.0.2/docs/src/Control-Concurrent-Async.html) library (for self-studying purpose) and have a question regarding the `waitBoth` function.

The library implements the function as follows:

```
waitBoth :: Async a -> Async b -> IO (a,b)
waitBoth left right =
  atomically $ do
    a <- waitSTM left
           `orElse`
         (waitSTM right >> retry)
    b <- waitSTM right
    return (a,b)
```

And I was wondering if I could implement the function in terms of the `waitEither` and `wait` functions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections     #-}

waitBoth :: Async a -> Async b -> IO (a,b)
waitBoth a b =
  waitEither a b >>= \case
    Left res  -> (res,) <$> wait b
    Right res -> (,res) <$> wait a
```

Are these two versions exactly the same or is there any subtle semantical or performance differences?

Comment: I think that they are semantically identical, but only because an `Async` moves monotonically from empty to full (or empty to `cancel`-ed) and the API enforces this. If you were dealing with `TVar`s they would be different because the former is in a single transaction, while the latter is two separate transactions.

Comment: (by "the former/latter" I mean your two implementations above)

Comment: For those who are wondering about the difference between `waitSTM left` and ```waitSTM left `orElse` (waitSTM right >> retry)```: after staring at this for a while, I believe the difference is related to exceptions. If `left` retries, the former will `retry` whereas the latter will give `right` a chance to throw an exception before retrying.